# Loading PowerShell7 scripts upon VSCode startup?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, profile

I would like to move from PowerShell 5.1 to 7x using it in VSCode.
In PowerShell 5.1. I was able to load .ps1 scripts upon startup by simply putting them in `$env:userprofile\documents\Windows PowerShell`
This doesn't work for PowerShell 7. How do I recreate that?

Comment: Use the `$PROFILE` variable on both versions to find your Profile Script. Copy the code you want from your old version to the new.